# How to use the node google client api to get user profile with already fetched token?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-client

Getting a user profile info through **curl**

```
curl -i https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me -H "Authorization: Bearer a-google-account-access-token"
```

Getting a user profile info through **node https get request**

```
const https = require('https');

function getUserData(accessToken) {
    var options = {        
                    hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
                    port: 443,
                    path: '/userinfo/v2/me',
                    method: 'GET',
                    json: true,
                    headers:{
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken            
                   }
            };
    console.log(options);
    var getReq = https.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log("\nstatus code: ", res.statusCode);
        res.on('data', function(response) {
            try {
                var resObj = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log("response: ", resObj);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });

    getReq.end();
    getReq.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }); 

}

var token = "a-google-account-access-token";
getUserData(token)
```

How can I use this [google node api client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to get the user profile info **provided that I already have the access token**? I can use the code above to get the profile but I thought it's probably better off to use the google api library to do it, but I can't figure out how to do that using this node google api client library.

A temporary access token can be acquired through playing this [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/qt6dCgnmWpcVvdLdoXuoPx13oZ9eBR08ZJ_xTrMXM6A#)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can retrieve the user profile using [the google node API client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). In this case, please retrieve the access token and refresh token as the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`. The sample script is as follows. When you use this sample, please set your ACCESS TOKEN.

### Sample script :

```
var google = require('googleapis').google;
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2();
oauth2Client.setCredentials({access_token: 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE'});
var oauth2 = google.oauth2({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  version: 'v2'
});
oauth2.userinfo.get(
  function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    } else {
       console.log(res);
    }
});
```

### Result :

```
{
  id: '#####',
  name: '#####',
  given_name: '#####',
  family_name: '#####',
  link: '#####',
  picture: '#####',
  gender: '#####',
  locale: '#####'
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: yes, you misunderstood my question. The situation is that I already have the AccessToken, I don't want to and no need to use the api's oauth2 to retrieve the AccessToken. I am looking for how to use this api if I already have the AccessToken.

Comment: @s-hunter I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. The updated script can be used by your access token. And at this script, the access token is not retrieved.

Comment: Confirmed and accepted your answer. Would you share how did you come to this solution? I can't seem to find any documentation or sample code from that repo for these two methods, oauth2Client.setCredentials and oauth2.userinfo.get. Did you back trace the source code?

Comment: @s-hunter I always get the information from README.md and the source of each client library for using Google APIs. About ``setCredentials``, I get it from [the document](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/README.md). From this information, I could get how to use ``oauth2Client``. Then, about ``oauth2.userinfo.get`` for Node.js, I checked [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/da49e69e272653cb94a248e60f73656b90ba387f/apis/oauth2/v2.ts). I think that there is more effective ways. But in this case, I did above. If this was not useful, I'm sorry.

Comment: @s-hunter hey. i need to do same but i don't know why not working for me. i have added package googleapis . my script stopped in second line. any other package needed or its works only on googleapis?

Comment: use an older version of the googleapis would work for the above code, ex: npm install googleapis@22.2.0

Comment: How do you know how to do it? Where is it written in the first place?

Comment: @Gherman I cannot understand about your comment. I apologize for my poor English skill. If you want to know the information above script, you can see it at [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client).

Comment: @Tanaike I just can't find where it is written about OAuth2 profile data in these docs. There are docs about how to get tokens but not user id, email, etc. Where is `userinfo` field described?

Comment: @Gherman I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. I checked [github of googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/6817c39728b199b82af5478de5aef2cda51e969c/src/apis/oauth2).

Comment: @Tanaike I understand that github of googleapis should be what I am searching for. Hoever github of googleapis does not say about `google.oauth2` and `oauth2.userinfo`. Can't find it there.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for trying. I just wonder how you learned about if it's not in the docs

Comment: @Gherman When I use Google API, if I couldn't find the document for the API I want to use, I check the library for each language. In my case, I usually check the libraries for using Google APIs of golang, python and node.js. From these information, I can know about how to use. I think that there might be better ways. But in the current stage, I check them. If these were not useful for you, I have to apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike This is still working fine. Do you know if there is some other library that can be used for the this scenario where I have google accessToken from the client and want to fetch google user data based on that accessToken on node server?

Comment: @Nenad Vracar Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about other library except for [googleapis for Node.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) for using Google APIs. But when I could find other better libraries, I would like to tell you. I apologize that I cannot tell them soon.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your response and also your answer helped me a lot with auth implementation in my project.

Comment: @Nenad Vracar Thank you for replying. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 11):

**2021 Solution**

This answer may divert from the originally asked question but I think it will be useful for some people who are getting google user information in the backend by generating AuthUrl and sending it to the client side and then receiving the data response in the call back URL after the user gives permission from the client side.

Some global declarations

```
import { google } from "googleapis";
const Oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  googleCredentials.CLIENT_ID,
  googleCredentials.CLIENT_SECRET,
  googleCredentials.REDIRECT_URI
);
```

Generate the Auth URL with the scopes

```
const SCOPE = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', // get user info
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',   // get user email ID and if its verified or not
];
const auth_url = Oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: "offline",
  scope: SCOPE,
  prompt: "consent",
  state: "GOOGLE_LOGIN",
});
return res.json({ url: auth_url });    // send the Auth URL to the front end
```

Get the user data in the callback

```
let code = req.query.code;    // get the code from req, need to get access_token for the user 
let { tokens } = await Oauth2Client.getToken(code);    // get tokens
let oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2();    // create new auth client
oauth2Client.setCredentials({access_token: tokens.access_token});    // use the new auth client with the access_token
let oauth2 = google.oauth2({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  version: 'v2'
});
let { data } = await oauth2.userinfo.get();    // get user info
console.log(data);
```

Feel free to discuss in the comments if there's any confusion or error

Comment: Amazing it worked. Can you please share where did you get the relevant documentation because i am not able to find doc about google api on google, ironic.

Comment: Hi @Deiknymi ! I'm sorry I don't remember the documentation its been a long time, you can search for official docs on the internet or refer to a youtube video or blogs.

Comment: well looks like the path of suffering is the the true path.

Answer (score 4):

You can also decode the `id_token` that's in the response from `oAuth2Client.getToken()`.

Remember that you need to have necessary scopes enabled for your app for the response to have this `id_token`. For an example, let's say we just need the user's email. So we'll use,

```html
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

To decode the token,

```js
const response = await oAuth2Client.getToken(code);
const userInfo = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(response.tokens.id_token.split('.')[1], 'base64').toString());

console.log(userInfo);
```

This will output,

```json
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "10769150350006150715113082367",
  "at_hash": "HK6E_P6Dh8Y93mRNtsDB1Q",
  "hd": "example.com",
  "email": "jsmith@example.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "iat": 1353601026,
  "exp": 1353604926,
  "nonce": "0394852-3190485-2490358"
}
```

This token simply is a [`JWT`](https://jwt.io/) object which can be decoded eaisily. You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo) and see even Google recommends this. The advantage of this method is that you don't have to make an extra request to Google APIs to get user's info.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on this anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780714/140164

Here is another shorter way to achieve the same results.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2()
const tokenInfo = await oauth2Client.getTokenInfo(*YourAccessToken*);
console.log(tokenInfo);
```

Comment: it will provide only info inside token, which includes email but not e.g. name