# AWS Cognito Google Identity Provider Get Profile First & Last Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-authentication

I've setup AWS Cognito with a Google identity provider as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html.

Users can login but I only seem to get back the users `email`, `email_verified` and a `username` like `Google_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` in my auth callback and cognito login/signup Lambda hooks.

Is there a way to also get the users first & last name?

I've set `profile email openid` as the authorize scope.

Also tried using `googleapis` npm package to call `oauth2.userinfo.get` as in [How to use the node google client api to get user profile with already fetched token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780218/how-to-use-the-node-google-client-api-to-get-user-profile-with-already-fetched-t/46780714) but the access token I get back is from Cogntio not google which is why I assume this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've not tried this but I know the theory.

In Cognito, go to Federation -> Attribute Mapping -> Select Google from the tabs -> Check given_name and map it to Given Name, Check family_name and map it to Family Name.

EDIT: Also, you will need to parse the Identity Token from Cognito rather than the Access Token I think.

Comment: What a hero  thanks for pointing this out seems obvious now I know

Comment: given_name  + family_name = Google Name

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i map access token and refresh token?

Comment: How do I get the phone number if the IDP is Azure AD - i.e. what do I populate Cognito's SAML attribute with? e.g. for email, you populate the field with "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" what is the equivalent for phone number