# NodeJS - Is there a way to get the current logged in user with the Google API?

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client, passport-google-oauth

Is it possible to get the current logged in user (email, name etc.) from the refreshToken, accessToken, or by a method similar to this [Retrieve profile information for a signed-in user](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed-in_user) in NodeJS?

Comment: please edit your question and include your autorisation code.

Comment: Thank you! What exactly is the autorisation code?`

Comment: The code that you are using to login a user.  specifically what scopes you are using when requesting authorization to the users data.

Comment: This is the scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780714/11072506

Comment: @HamzaKhuswan that will only work if they are requesting the profile scope

Comment: @HamzaKhuswan That could fix it; thank you!

Comment: @DaImTo Do I have to add the profile scope?

Comment: @STh yes you will need to add the profile scope to see the full profile information but if you just wait their name and email then you can just go though caledar.get it has name and email there not sure if they had to have set up name there or not.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers! I especially wanted to get their google id's... Anyway your answer below will fix it for more persons... @DaImTo

Comment: userinfo endpoint does not 100% of the time return the userinfo data.  but you should always get the sub back at the very least which is their google id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the userinfo endpoint to request some of this information.

```
https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=XXXX
```

The one issue is that you will need to add the **profile** scope to your authroization request  then you will get back something like this

```
{
  "sub": "117475532672775346",
  "name": "Linda Lawton",
  "given_name": "Linda",
  "family_name": "Lawton",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

You could then also go though the google people api [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) which will give you even more information.

However you cant get email back from the userinfo endpoint without requesting the email scope but there is a trick you really dont need to as you are using the google calendar scope.

if you use [calendar.get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%7D) and request the users primary calendar the calendar name is their email address.

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"Qvsbvz0_YlxYi3Ml2Fd7A\"",
 "id": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "Linda Lawton ",
 "description": "test",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
 "conferenceProperties": {
  "allowedConferenceSolutionTypes": [
   "hangoutsMeet"
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: check the following tutorial on how to add additional scopes to your code https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs  scopes is just a string array